# Running python scripts in Anaconda environment through Windows cmd

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda, scheduled-tasks, pyinstaller

I have the following goal: I have a python script, which should be running in my custom Anaconda environment. And this process needs to be automatizated.

The first thing I've tried was to create an .exe file of my script using pyinstaller in the Anaconda command prompt, opened in my environment. And put the .exe into Windows Task Scheduler. But I did not succeeded cause my script seems to be too complex, contain too many imports so pyinstaller didn't create the .exe.

The next thing I thought of was an attempt to run my script using Windows CMD with appropriate attributes, and also put it into Windows Task Scheduler.

Now my question is if there is a way to set up Task Scheduler so it could run CMD with attributes, which would activate my environment and with this environment run my script right away? I need this to be done automatically once a day at a given time.

**Update 3**: am I blind or what?
[image]
I mean, here it is:[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could

1. Create a `.bat` file (e.g. `run_python_script.bat`) with contents shown below.
2. Create task in "Task Scheduler" to run the `.bat` file.

#### 1.a. The .bat file contents with conda environments

1. Check your `<condapath>`. Your `conda.exe` is located at `<condapath>/Scripts`.
2. Put into your .bat file

```
call "<condapath>\Scripts\activate.bat" <env_name> & cd "<folder_for_your_py_script>" & python <scriptname.py> [<arguments>]
```

- `<env_name>` is the name of the conda environment.
- `<folder_for_your_py_script>` is the folder that contains `<scriptname.py>`
- `<scriptname.py>` is the script you want to start.
- `[<arguments>]` represent the optional arguments (if you need to give arguments to your script)

#### 1.b. The .bat file contents with venv

```
"<path_to_python_exe>" "<path_to_python_script>" [<arguments>]
```

where

- `<path_to_python_exe>` is the path to your python executable. If you are using a virtual environment (`venv`), then use the `python.exe` found in the `/venv/Scripts` folder
- `<path_to_python_script>` is the path to your python script.
- `[<arguments>]` represent the optional arguments (if you need to give arguments to your script)

#### 2. Creating task in Task Scheduler

1. Go to "Task Scheduler" -> "Create Basic Task"
2. Give the name & timing info
3. Add to the "Program/Script" the path to your `run_python_script.bat`.

---

#### Appendix: Creating `venv` with Anaconda

It seems that `conda create` command does not create similar virtual environments as `python -m venv` command. To create normal python virtual environment with the [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

1. Check your `<condapath>`. Your `conda.exe` is located at `<condapath>/Scripts`.
2. Create virtual environment to folder you want (let's call it `venv_folder`), by running following command in  `<venv_folder>`

```
<condapath>\python.exe -m venv venv
```

3. Now, your `<path_to_python_exe>` will be `<venv_folder>\venv\Scripts.python.exe`.
4. If you need to install packages to this virtual environment, you use

```
<venv_folder>\venv\Scripts.python.exe -m pip install <package_name>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! Unfortunately, there is no such file "python.exe" in D:\...\Anaconda3\envs\One\Scripts. But there is a file "ipython.exe". I've tried to do the steps you provided with "ipython.exe" but it haven't worked. The black CMD window appered with a bunch of text in it, but it disappeared too soon to investigate. The containings of the .bat file I've created are following: "D:/.../Anaconda3/envs/One/Scripts/ipython3.exe" "D:/.../New/am.py"

Comment: Ok, here's what I managed to do: I've created a .bat file with the following line: %windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" D:\Users\Dmitry\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat D:\Users\Dmitry\Anaconda3\envs\One.

This now opens the Anaconda Prompt with my custom environment activated! This is one part of the goal. Now if I type "python my_script.py" it will execute my script in this environment perfectly, just as it should. 

But I cannot make it automatically run Anaconda prompt and INSIDE THIS prompt immediately run script. How do I modify .bat to do so?

Comment: I downloaded Anaconda to test this myself and seems that the environments created with `conda create` are not "regular python virtual environments". I edited the answer to include instructions how to use `venv` with Anaconda.

Comment: The thing is I have to use only my custom environment, that I've created in Anaconda, because it contains some specific modules, that work only with Anaconda (i.e. they have actual supported versions, and they don't work in regular Python (i think it's due to they are made for Linux)). Thus, I have to run my custom environment, created in Anaconda and run scripts in it (I can do so by either running Spyder from Anaconda Navigator with my environmet and run from there, or by running "Anaconda Prompt (my_env)" and typing (as in regular Python) "python my_script.py".

Comment: I see. I updated the answer for conda environments.

Comment: Oh my gosh, the .bat file with what you provided works just perfect! My python script gets executed in my environment with all inner imports! It's great and I can't thank you enough! But there is a small issue appeared when I put the .bat into Task Scheduler. When the task is executed, the cmd window appears and immediately disappears. I've added "pause" line to the .bat, and it says it cannot open python script because it is missing in the directory (although it IS pretty much there, and I can start .bat manually with no problems). I've updated the main question

Comment: I tested the answer again and checked it works on Task Scheduler. On my PC, everything was ok. I can only think of two possible options (1) The folder or file has a typo (2) Some permission problem keeps the Task Scheduler from accessing the script. In that case, I would try to run a test script in another folder. So, when double clicking the `.bat`, does it  run the script? How about, if you move the bat to any other directory and double click? Does it work then, too?

Comment: 1) Yes, if I just double click the .bat it runs the script in my env, and it works perfectly.
2) I moved .bat and all python scripts to other local disc (to C:) and forgot to change the "cd ..." part in the .bat. Still it works just great.
3) Again in C: i changed the "cd ..." part and it's fine.
4) And, SURPRISINGLY, I set up the task in the Scheduler to execute everything from C: and it worked!!! Like what's wrong? Maybe it's because it was the Dropbox folder or secondary disk (D:)?

Comment: Good to hear you got it working.  I have to say that I don't know why the Task Scheduler could not access your Dropbox folder. Maybe it could be a topic of another question (on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), perhaps).

Comment: You can't imagine how greatful I am for your support! Even one big THANK YOU cannot be enough. I've lastly updated the question, maybe you can see difference

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! It works for the most part. I got into an issue where I needed to change directory when starting the process however. Basically, my CMD starts in drive  `H:\...`  and my Anaconda and scripts are all in `D:\Scripts\....`. The `cd script address` part didn't work for me because of that. To solve it, I only needed to add `/D`  after `cd` in the `cd "script address"...`   and it worked.