# Is there a way to run other python scripts in an Anaconda prompt throught my python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I'm trying to make a GUI for the image generating AI [VQGAN-CLIP](https://github.com/nerdyrodent/VQGAN-CLIP) since the args are hard to properly use.
VQGAN-CLIP uses Anaconda prompt with a virtual environment, created and called by this command in an Anaconda prompt window:

```
 conda create --name vqgan python=3.9
 conda activate vqgan
```

I then run this command in the Anaconda prompt, located at C:\vqgan\VQGAN-CLIP, and the AI starts generating the image

```
python generate.py -p "An apple" -i 10 -s 250 250 -cuts 10 -se 10
```

Now, if I want to run this exact command in a python script for the GUI (called vqgan-gui, located in the folder C:\vqgan), I thought I could use something like :

```py
os.system('python generate.py -p "An apple" -i 10 -s 250 250 -cuts 10 -se 10')
```

Or :

```py
command = 'python .\VQGAN-CLIP\generate.py -p "An apple" -i 10 -s 250 250 -cuts 10 -se 10' 
subprocess.run('conda activate vqgan', shell=True)
subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

Or this command (provided by this useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62984477/running-python-scripts-in-anaconda-environment-through-windows-cmd)):

```py
subprocess.run('call "%USERPROFILE%/anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" vqgan & cd "C:\vqgan\VQGAN-CLIP\" & python generate.py -p "An apple" -i 10 -s 250 250 -cuts 10 -se 10')
```

Turns out that all of them fail with similar exit codes like:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taming.models'
```

**My question is:**

- **Do I run the commands called through Anaconda prompt, called by my python GUI script? If so, how can I do this?**

**OR:**

- **Do I activate the virtual environment prior to the** *os.system("command")* **inside my python GUI script? If so, how can I do this?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like  you need to install `taming.models` in the environment

Comment: virtual environment should create special folder with `python.exe` and you can use `full\path\to\this\python.exe` instead of `activate.bat` to run code in this virtual environment